# ADSOpenObject getting failed with error code 0x80070035(The Network Path Was Not Found)

Tags: c++, cross-domain

I have a piece of code which is trying to execute the `ADsOpenObject` for URL `WinNT://domain1/user1`

```
HRESULT hr = ADsOpenObject(URL,NULL,NULL,ADS_READONLY_SERVER ,IID_IADsUser,(void**)&pUser);
```

This code is being executed from another domain called domain2 but the call is getting failed with error code 0x80070035(The Network Path Was Not Found) and it is taking 5-6 second before returning the error 0x80070035 .

What could be the reason that it is getting failed.

Comment: I don't know why do you put the tag domain-driven design...

Comment: Please ignore that tag.